# Is there a step-by-step process to setup Kerberos authentication for a Spark Client running against a Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, kerberos

I followed the documentation of Apache Spark and made all the necessary configuration changes but when I run spark-submit, I get the following error:

```
Exception encountered while connecting to the server : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
```

I would appreciate any help I can get with this.

This is the configuration that I have:

```
## Begin Kerberos configuration in spark-defaults.conf

spark.history.kerberos.enabled   true
spark.history.kerberos.principal spark/${HOSTNAME}@<REALM>
spark.history.kerberos.keytab    ${KEYTAB_HOME}/spark_svc_principal.keytab 

spark.yarn.keytab               ${KEYTAB_HOME}/hadoop.keytab 
spark.yarn.principal            hadoop/${HOSTNAME}@<REALM>
spark.yarn.kerberos.relogin.period  1m

## End Kerberos configuration in spark-defaults.conf


## Begin Kerberos configuration in hive-site.xml

    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name>
        <value>hadoop/_HOST@REALM</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>    
        <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file</name>    
        <value>${KEYTAB_HOME}/hadoop.keytab</value>    
    </property>   
    
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
        <value>KERBEROS</value>
    </property> 
    
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
        <value>hadoop/_HOST@REALM</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
        <value>${KEYTAB_HOME}/hadoop.keytab</value>    
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

## End Kerberos configuration in hive-site.xml

I am not sure if I got this right.
```

And here are the arguments that I am passing to spark-submit:

```
"SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS='-Xmx4g' \
    ${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh \
    --executor-memory 5g \
    --driver-cores 4 \
    --num-executors 15"
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
the below approach will solve your problem,

`KERBEROS_KEYTAB_PATH=/home/user/user.keytab` and `KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL=user@NAME.COM` .

**Approach 1: with kinit command**

**step 1: kinit and proceed with spark-submit**

```
kinit -kt ${KERBEROS_KEYTAB_PATH} ${KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL}
```

**step 2: Run `klist` and verify Kerberization is correctly working for the logged in user.**

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_XXXXXXXXX_XXXXXX
Default principal: user@NAME.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/30/2020 15:52:28  07/31/2020 01:52:28  krbtgt/NAME.COM@NAME.COM
        renew until 08/06/2020 15:52:28
```

**step 3: replace the spark code with spark session**

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).appName("TEST1").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

**step 4:  Run spark-submit as below.**

```
 $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class com.test.load.Data \
     --master yarn \
     --deploy-mode cluster \
     --driver-memory 2g \
     --executor-memory 2g \
     --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 2 \
     --conf "spark.driver.cores=2" \
     --name "TEST1" \
     --principal ${KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL} \
     --keytab ${KERBEROS_KEYTAB_PATH} \
     --conf spark.files=$SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml \
     /home/user/sparkproject/Test-jar-1.0.jar 2> /home/user/logs/test1.log
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
      <value>KERBEROS</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
      <value>/home/user/user.keytab</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
      <value>hive/_HOST@NAME.COM</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.Domain</name>
      <value>NAME.COM</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.keystore.password</name>
      <value>password</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.keystore.path</name>
      <value>/home/user/hive-jks/hive.jks</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am sorry. I should have been a little more specific. I am running Spark Thrift Server over YARN. And I was wondering how to setup the configuration entries in "spark-defaults.conf" and "hive-site.xml" for enabling Kerberos authentication.

Comment: whether your spark & hadoop are in a single cluster or you are connecting spark in local to external hadoop cluster.

Comment: updated the answer with hive-site.xml changes, please let me know for any help.

Comment: I would say both - we have Spark data load processes running locally on the Hadoop cluster as well as client applications coming through Jupyter Notebooks and such. If you have details of how to configure the clients, that would be great. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: yeah. this is an example of production environment you can have for deploy cluster mode of your spark jobs. it should work as edge node  -> hadoop cluster connection (RHEL edge to RHEL based HDP cluster) in my case.

Comment: Can you run `klist` command in the edge node?? And share me the result??

Comment: Added to the main message. I am using placeholders to obfuscate names.

Comment: Run `klist` and see the Kerberos ticket validity

Comment: It shows above the validity as 24 hours ending at 14:37 on 7/31 at which time, I am guessing it will auto-renew.

Comment: yeah, then you are good to connect with the kerberos.

Comment: I also added the arguments that I am passing to spark-submit to the main message. Do I need to pass arguments for Kerberos principal and keytab there as well? I read in the documentation that having those values in the "spark-defaults.conf" is adequate.

I am still a bit puzzled that I am getting the error, especially if the configuration above looks correct.

Comment: run `kinit` it will ask you the password auth in terminal. once password auth is successful then run spark submit with your logged in kerberized user.

Comment: I still get the same error. I ran **kinit** using the Spark service principal keytab, verified that the principal shows ups in **klist**  and then ran the spark-submit. I read in other posts here in Stack Overflow that I may need to have a custom **hdfs-site.xml** for Spark similar to **hive-site.xml** since Spark doesn't pick up the config from the default locations. I will give that a try next. Thanks very much for your help.